# How to aggregate and recover original columns in R without partial duplicates?

Tags: r, merge, dataframe, aggregate

I want to find the minimum value aggregating by gene:

```
a <- data.frame(probe=c("probe1","probe2","probe3","probe4"), gene=c("gene1","gene1","gene2","gene1"), value=c(.001,.1,.05,.001))
#   probe  gene  value
# 1 probe1 gene1 0.001
# 2 probe2 gene1 0.100
# 3 probe3 gene2 0.050
# 4 probe4 gene1 0.001
```

So I did this:

```
    aggregated <- aggregate(value~gene, data=a, FUN=min)
#    gene value
# 1 gene1 0.001
# 2 gene2 0.050
b <- merge(aggregated, a) 
#    gene value  probe
# 1 gene1 0.001 probe1 
# 2 gene1 0.001 probe4 
# 3 gene2 0.050 probe3
```

But because probe1 and probe4 have the same value, gene1 is duplicated, and then I need to choose one of the two columns (no matter which one). So I could do this:

```
# THIS IS THE OUTPUT THAT I WANT
c <- aggregate(b, by=list(b$gene), function(x) x[1])[,-1]
#    gene value  probe
# 1 gene1 0.001 probe1
# 2 gene2 0.050 probe3
```

The problem is that I use this in a loop, so it will give an error if I apply it on a dataframe without duplicates:

```
aggregate(c, by=list(b$gene), function(x) x[1])[,-1]
# Error in aggregate.data.frame(c, by = list(b$gene), function(x) x[1]) : arguments must have same length
```

I could check for the existence of duplicate probe-gene pairs before applying the second aggregate but I'm sure there's a better way.

**EDIT**: there was a mistake in my code. This actually works perfectly

```
b <- merge(aggregate(value~gene, data=a, FUN=min), a); 
aggregate(b, by=list(b$gene), function(x) x[1])[,-1]
```

But the question remains, is there a less roundabout way to do this?

Comment: There is a mistake in your code. In the final line, it should be `by=list(c$gene)` not `by=list(b$gene)`. Then it doesn't give you an error.

Comment: oh, good catch. Still, is this the best way to do this?

Comment: Is this what you need? `library(plyr); ddply(a, .(gene), function(x) x[which.min(x$value),])`

Comment: Thanks @kohske, that actually works, but for my 45K row real dataset it takes 10+ minutes, as opposed to the few seconds it takes to do `b <- merge(aggregate(value~gene, data=a, FUN=min), a); aggregate(b, by=list(b$gene), function(x) x[1])[,-1]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An option is to use package: data.table. This should be very fast:

```
library(data.table)
a <- data.table(a)
setkeyv(a, c("gene"))

a[, list(min(value), probe[which.min(value)]), by = gene]
```

Comment: I've never used data.table. I'll have to check it out!